# what does this mean? bash and nagios programming

Tags: bash, nagios

i'm triying to understand some program on nagios, it is about counting warnings :

countWarnings=$(/usr/local/nagios/bin/nagiostats | grep "Ok/Warn/Unk/Crit:" | sed 's/[[:space:]]//g' | cut -d"/" -f5)

this is the part of the code i don't get

what is the sed part doing and cut part

i'm new in this kind of programming, really need help

Comment: Have you started with `man cut`? Any basic `sed` tutorial will tell you `s` is for text replacement.

Comment: Usually, "please explain this code" questions are considered too broad to be within our rules unless you're **extremely** specific about what you do and don't know -- showing your prior research ("I read `man sed`, but don't understand how the paragraph about *foo* applies to what we're doing here") helps. Right now, an answer would have to go into explaining regular expressions and character classes, which is quite a lot of scope that could be avoided if we knew more precisely what you were having trouble with.

Comment: BTW, have you tried running the pipeline by hand with the last part or two taken off? Comparing output of `/usr/local/nagios/bin/nagiostats | grep "Ok/Warn/Unk/Crit:"` to what you get adding `| sed 's/[[:space:]]//g'` onto the end is a pretty good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about nagios, but supposing you understand what `grep` is doing, the rest is:

`sed` (stream editor) is `s`ubstituting (erasing) all white spaces for nothing (or a white space, whatever is between the second and third slash '//'), including tabs and linebreaks (this is what `[:space:]` stands for), `g`lobally. This combines to `'s/[[:space:]]//g'`

The result goes to `cut`, that will use as delimiter (set with `-d`) slashes "/" and will select and print only field (`-f`) 5.

By the way, use code function when showing posting codes to StackOverflow, makes easier to read and answer (for instance, I do not know if you wrote `'s/[[:space:]]//g'` or `'s/[[:space:]]/ /g'` just from looking).